# pytonet, не могу подключить

Tags: python, c#, .net, pythonnet

нужно из c# файла вызвать python скрипт, но получаю ошибки:

> Вызвано исключение: "System.TypeInitializationException" в Python.Runtime.dll

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.TypeInitializationException" в Python.Runtime.dll

> Инициализатор типа "Delegates" выдал исключение.

pytonet устанавливал в visual studio через Nuget, самая последняя версия.
Сборка стоит на x64.

Код:

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

namespace code
{
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Python\Python310.dll";
using (Py.GIL())
    {
     dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
     Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
     dynamic sin = np.sin;
     Console.WriteLine(sin(5));
     Console.WriteLine(a * b);
     Console.ReadKey();
     }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проверьте путь `C:\Python\Python310.dll` возможно библиотека не там.

Comment: @DaniilLoban она там, проверял. Про бывал разные версии python, все так же

Comment: Опубликуйте полный стек ошибки и желательно на английском (если есть такая возможность)

Comment: у меня бмблиотека так называется `python310.dll`

Comment: @DaniilLoban в Windows регистр не имеет значения, в Linux имеет.